# PHP Directory issues , cannot go back directory using ( ../)

Tags: php, html

I have correctly placed my file directories, with all correct spellings, but it is still bringing an error that the directory is not found.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","ppro");
// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }



$loginusername = $_GET["loginusername"];
$loginpassword = $_GET["loginpassword"]; 




$sql="SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `staff` WHERE `username` ='$loginusername' AND `password`='$loginpassword' ";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
                /*
 // Return the number of rows in result set

 printf("Result set has %d rows",$rowcount);
       */
 $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result); 

 if($rowcount==1){

       session_start();
       $_SESSION["user"] = $_GET["loginusername"];


      /*   USES TITLE TO DISTINGUISH WHICH PAGE IT WILL DISPLAY TO THE USER NURSE WILL GO TO NURSE'S PAGE    */
      $sql = "SELECT title FROM staff WHERE username = '$loginusername'";
      $result = $con->query($sql);
       /*   RETRIEVING TITLE   */

      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $title =  $row["title"];
      }
      } else {
      echo "0 results";
      }

       if($title == "doctor"){

            session_start();
            $_SESSION["user"] = $_GET["loginusername"];


            if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
                  header("Location: ../doctor.php");



             }else{
                  header("Location: ../index.php ");
             }


      } elseif ($title == "clerk") {

            session_start();
            $_SESSION["user"] = $_GET["loginusername"];

            if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
                  header("Location: ../clerk.php ");


             }else{
                  header("Location: ../index.php ");
             }






       }




 }else{

      echo "<script> alert('USERNAME OR PASSWORD IS WRONG !!'); </script>";
      header("Location: ../error.php ");

}


 // Free result set

 }



?>
```

I have correctly placed my file directories, with all correct spellings, but it is still bringing an error that the directory is not found. I have also tried require or include and they are also not working so i am confused.
Thankyou.

Comment: Parameterize your query and hash your users passwords. This is very insecure. Also `exit` after `header` calls or the code keeps going..

Comment: Your code gives me anxiety. It is vulnerable to SQL injections. This is also a bad  practice to do a login. Use prepared statements, encrypt your passwords. There is a function for it `password_hash()`.

Answer (score 1):

try removing the `..` (two dots) so it uses a relative link to the domain.
The `header("Location....` is a redirection, and what you put after `Location:` need to make sens to the browser.

```
header("Location: /error.php ");
```

using the code above, if i'm accessing `localhost/test/index.php` it will redirect me to `localhost/error.php`

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location):

> The **Location** response header indicates the URL to redirect a page to.

Which means, it expects an URL not a path

Use `header('Location: /index.php');` instead.